# ActionSricpt 3 - Move to the certain scene

Tags: actionscript

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at CompangleComplete_fla::MainTimeline/loop()[CompangleComplete_fla.MainTimeline::frame119:205]
```

I got this error.

When the player touch the "black rectangle", supposed to move to the next scene.
I try to check where is the problem, then I try this

```
if(endpoint==false){
if(player.hitTestObject(back.other)){
endpoint==true;
trace("next scene");}
```

the code run without error.
But then I try this,

```
if(endpoint==false){
if(player.hitTestObject(back.other)){
endpoint==true;
gotoAndPlay(2, "Scene 9");}
```

I got error like above.
The code for my `gotoAndPlay(2, "Scene 9")` is wrong. How I should change it?

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a method `loop()` being executed repeatedly. My guess is that `Scene 9` does not contain one of the objects referenced in that loop. You can pinpoint the specific line of code by debugging the movie within Flash (`ctrl + shift + enter`).

Without more code it is hard to determine exactly what you are doing, but if you must change scenes I recommend stopping any loops/`ENTER_FRAME` listeners first, then starting them again in the new scene.